# Difference between individual account and team account

Tags: bitbucket

When you create an bitbucket account you can choose between individual account and 5 user team. I am not getting the difference since when you create an individual account you can create a Team as well and manage it. Could anyone explain to me the difference between individual account and team account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The team account feature has been removed, as of today's team-faq on bitbucket site.

Answer (score 1):

Plan details aside, there are indeed few differences between a normal and a team account. Under the hood, a team account is just a normal account record with a flag set.
The main difference is that team accounts can be administered by other users. One can also create and fork repos into a team account. Regular accounts do not have that ability.

The fact that a team account is based on the standard model also means that you can login with it and use it to pull/push with.

Reference : [Erik van Zijst](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitbucket-users/TzNJsU9rAE0)